# kendo ui context menu is not working when Kendo ui editor id target

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor, kendo-contextmenu

Kendo UI Context Menu is not working when its target is the Kendo UI Editor's id:

```
<textarea id="keditor" kendo-editor kendo-toolbar style="width: 100%; overflow: scroll">
</textarea>
```

script:

```
$("#client-context-menu").kendoContextMenu({
    target: "#keditor",
    dataSource: response.Item.AgreementParameters
});
```

Comment: When you say that it's not working, what exactly do you mean? Is nothing happening? Are you getting an exception or an error message?

Answer (score 2):

This is not very visibly documented, but Kendo's editor has [two very different work modes](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/editor/modes): classic and inline.

> If you use the default **textarea** element for initializing the Editor,
>   the Editor assumes its classic mode. The textarea is not visible and
>   is used to hold the value of the widget. You can type in the
>   contenteditable **iframe** that is created.
>
> If you initialize the Editor from a **div** element, the widget assumes
>   its inline mode. The  element is content-editable and is used by
>   the widget to return its value.

In your case, the element is a textarea, so the editor's content is in an iframe, so the right-click is in another context and doesn't trigger the context menu.

If you bind the editor to a div, it works, see sample: https://dojo.telerik.com/@GaloisGirl/iTowIkEW